# imshow flicker reaction when showing two images

Tags: python, opencv

I have an OpenCV video that I'm trying to resize, but when I use the resize function the window flicker. As an output I have a random video with a resolution of 1920x1080 at 60 fps. My screen is at the same resolution. I'm trying to resize at a lower scale but i have the problem froH above.

Here is the code itself

```
import cv2 as cv

def rescaleFrame(frame, scale=0.75):
    width = int(frame.shape[1]*scale)
    height = int(frame.shape[0]*scale)
    dimensions = (width, height)

    return cv.resize(frame, dimensions, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

capture = cv.VideoCapture('video_test.mp4')

while True:
    isTrue, frame=capture.read()
    frame_resized = rescaleFrame(frame, scale=0.2)
    cv.imshow('Video', frame)
    cv.imshow('Video', frame_resized)
    if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF==ord('d'):
        break
capture.release()
cv.destroyAllwindows()
```

Comment: `cv.imshow('Video Resized', frame_resized)`. Show the resized frames in a different window!

Comment: this question doesn't even use `resizeWindow`, it merely uses imshow twice with the same window name...